# Usage of 'this' in a sentence/punctuation

Tags: sentence-construction, british-english

The fight was well fought but violent--this made it a tough watch.

The car soaks up fuel and is tough to drive, that being said, it looks good.

The story has  surreal overtones-- there are parts that cross into fantasy.

On these sentences does 'there/this' constiutute a independent clause and need a semi-colon or conjunction such as 'and' or can em-dash be used.

Answer (score 0):

Both clauses in each of your sentences are independent and could be connected by semi-colons or each could be punctuated with a full-stop. An em-dash is the unruliest of punctuation marks—it can be used to separate independent clauses which are semantically connected, especially in informal prose.

Comment: What is the term when the first independent sentence relates directly to the - 'this' starting sentence. They are both independent sentences but the second is relying on the first.

Comment: The term *asyndeton* refers  to the phenomenon of clauses that lack some kind of linking word.  But your sentence are not unusual except in terms of their punctuation.  **This** and **that** can refer back to the gist of an earlier statement.